# Using <script> tags in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert an html/css/js template into a React.js application. However, the template uses 2 files inside script tags.

```
<script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" defer=""></script>
<script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="nicepage.js" defer=""></script>
```

I tried using Helmet and ScriptTag to add these files into my React.js code, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried:

```
function App() {

  return (
      <div>

          <ScriptTag type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />
          <ScriptTag type="text/javascript" src="nicepage.js" />

....
```

I get:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: You not supposed to set the `type` attribute anymore in HTML5. You not really suppose to use jQuery with React since jQuery modifies the DOM and React handles the DOM itself. Also you not suppose to use script tags with React since you probably use Node to compile it all into one script file.

Comment: So there is no easy way to do this then?

Comment: Yes, it is very easy, just `import` the JavaScript. Or you could always resort to the dirty way of just putting them in the `index.html` file.

Comment: you can also put these scripts into <head> of public/index.html. But this way scripts would be in the whole app

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should not use jQuery with react because JQuery modifies the DOM and react handles all DOM modifications. anyway if you want to get tons of bugs you could add JQuery to index.html in the public folder of your react app.

Comment: The question is not about that. The src could be "myVeryAwesomeLegacyCodeThatINeedHereForNow.js"

Comment: Adding the scripts inside the public index.html did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: it actually is, becuse he was trying to load them in App component at root level of the page, but if he tries to add some legacy js code in a particular component this is not gonna work and could get buggier and buggier. you should not do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to use jQuery in ReactJS.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
  }, [])
  return (
    <b>Your code</b>
  )
}
export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: This method worked too when I moved the files in the public folder. Thank you.